# Pay Website => User

Tags: php, paypal

I am finishing a website in which I have incorporated collections with IPN, and the truth, I'm very happy because I works great.

The question or problem I find is that I need to also pay users in certain cases from the website itself.

Someone could give an example of a payment function specific email? ... In PHP with Paypal Premium account.

I assume that when payment is ordered I also enter my ipn.php to be processed in the same way that happens when my page becomes ... is not it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Greetings to all.

Comment: payment function specific email? . what do u mean?

Comment: Php code to send pay ... My website pay a sum of money by sending email to a user

Comment: Then ... its or not possible make a pay with a Premium account in PHP???? .... how?
... If not ... with a Bussiness acount??? ... how???

tyvm